# Механизм работы COUNT() в MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, count

Почему для того, чтобы посчитать количество повторяющихся значений в поле, можно написать:

```
SELECT *, COUNT(phone) 
FROM registered_phones
GROUP BY phone HAVING COUNT(1)>1;
```

А для того, чтобы посчитать количество неповторяющихся значений, нужно писать:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM (
SELECT DISTINCT phone FROM registered_phones
) t;
```

и нельзя написать:

```
SELECT DISTINCT phone, COUNT(phone) FROM registered_phones;
```

Этот последний запрос возвратит неверное значение. Чем это обусловлено?

**UPD:**

Также я заметила, что всё-таки вернуть верное количество неповторяющихся значений можно следующим запросом:

```
SELECT DISTINCT phone, COUNT(DISTINCT phone) FROM registered_phones;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `SELECT COUNT(*) 
>   FROM (
>   SELECT DISTINCT phone FROM registered_phones
>   ) t;`

Выбрать `phone`, отбросить повторяющиеся и подсчитать количество оставшихся

> `SELECT DISTINCT phone, count(phone) FROM registered_phones;`

Для всех записей вывести значения поля `phone` и количество записей в таблице, где `phone` IS NOT NULL. Из пар (`phone`, `count`) отбросить дубликаты

Answer (score 2):

1. Потому что группируем по строке и смотрим, сколько раз она встречается

   ```
   SELECT *, COUNT(phone) 
   FROM registered_phones
   GROUP BY phone
   HAVING COUNT(1) > 1
   ```
2. Что мешает для поиска неповторяющихся значений написать так?

   ```
   SELECT *, COUNT(phone) 
   FROM registered_phones
   GROUP BY phone
   HAVING COUNT(1) = 1
   ```
3. Потому что данный запрос сначала сделает подсчёт количества - составит таблицу из `phone` и `count(phone)`, а потом пройдётся снова и выполнит `DISTINCT`, то есть удаление всех дубликатов (который будет бесполезен, т.к. мы используем агрегирующие функции и группировку):

   ```
   SELECT DISTINCT phone, COUNT(phone)
   FROM registered_phones
   GROUP BY phone;
   ```

   В этом случае надо использовать удаление дубликатов при подсчёте количества, то есть использовать `COUNT(DISTINCT phone)`

Comment: "Потому что данный запрос сначала сделает DISTINCT, то есть удаление всех дубликатов, а потом только посчитает количество" - так ведь именно это и кажется должно возвращать верное количество неповторяющихся значений (т.е. количество записей без дубликатов). Но результат показывает, что это не так. Почему так выходит?

Comment: @Ksenia не в том порядке случайно написал, подправил.